# SSH password not working

Tags: ssh, password

So I was trying to log into a server in SSH when all of a sudden it shows "password:." I try to type something where the password goes but whenever I press the keys nothing shows up. No words or letters or numbers.

Answer (score 0):

That is by design.  You don't want someone looking at your password over your shoulder as you enter it.  This is common practice with almost all password entry fields out there today, not just SSH.  Some servers will show *'s when entering the password, but I know Ubuntu 16 and 18 do not by default.

Comment: Thank you. Now where would I find the password for said server.

Comment: You would get that from the owner of the server.

Comment: So im trying to log into my own desktop computer from a laptop and I have got the IP for said desktop. I don't really know how to phrase this but who would the owner of the server be?

Comment: @bradyfcs you would log in using the same password that you use to log in to the desktop directly - if you don't remember that password (perhaps because you configured your desktop to log in automatically) you can follow these instructions to reset it: [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: what if my computer has multiple accounts

Comment: you setup the users and passwords.  If you do not remember them you will have to reset the passwords.  Have you customized the ssh config at all and limited who can log in?  That would also cause this problem if you are using the correct credentials.

Comment: ok thx u helped.